# SQL Query reg.ex. matching

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

i have a little problem figuring out what request (MySQL) would suit this requirements:

Table1

```
+++++++++++++++++
id| name
+++++++++++++++++
1 | John Smith
2 | Eric Smith
3 | Martha Smith
4 | Smith
5 | Ronald Smith Donald
6 | Marc Fisher
```

Table2

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++
regex | value1 | value2
+++++++++++++++++++++++
Smith | Mister | 356
Fisher| Sir    | 24
```

**To select result values as**

Result Set

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
id| name                | regex  | value1 | value2 
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
1 | John Smith          | Mister | 356
2 | Eric Smith          | Mister | 356
3 | Martha Smith        | Mister | 356
4 | Smith               | Mister | 356
5 | Ronald Smith Donald | Mister | 356
6 | Marc Fisher         | Sir    | 24
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use MySQL's [regexp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp):

```
select  *
from    Table1 t1
join    Table2 t2
on      t1.name regexp t2.regex
```

Funny things will occur if a name matches more than one `regex` in Table2.

Comment: Yeah, found it, thanks, might work it out. As i always used T-SQL i didnt knew MySQL had such function :)